# How can I get the index of a Qcheckbox within a QtabWidget object?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm working on a project using PyQt5, the slice of code I'm struggling with right now is something like that:

```
 def tab_strauss(self):
        tab1 = QWidget()
        a = QCheckBox("Ø 25 cm - 200 kN")
        b = QCheckBox("Ø 32 cm - 300 kN")
        c = QCheckBox("Ø 38 cm - 450 kN")
        d = QCheckBox("Ø 42 cm - 550 kN")
        e = QCheckBox("Ø 45 cm - 650 kN")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(a)
        layout.addWidget(b)
        layout.addWidget(c)
        layout.addWidget(d)
        layout.addWidget(e)
        tab1.setLayout(layout)

        return tab1
```

this is part of a QtabWidget,

```
def corpo(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        estaca = QTabWidget()
        estaca.addTab(self.tab_strauss(), "Strauss")....
```

I tried to create a list made of a, b, c, d, e to iterate over a for loop and verify thought an if statement if one of the checkbox was checked, but it didn't work out so well.

What I wanted to know is the index of the box checked, like if 'a' was checked it should give me a 0, 'b' a 1, 'c' a 2 and so on. This number would than be used just internally in another function. I'm accepting other ideas as well.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Also please don't try to emphasize code by using asterisks or any other form that would make your syntax wrong. Have a look at [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html).

Comment: It's my first question on stack, but right after I posted it, I noticed how bad the asterisk looked. I'll try to edit. I'll also look your doc link. And sorry @eyllanesc, but I don't know exactly how to do this minimal example as of right now, but in short all I got is something like this: https://postimg.cc/XGVKF0GG, the int value of the marked box index would be used as a reference point in another part of the code. It means that I wanted to know which box was checked and turn its position into a number, for example: if the 2nd box was marked I would get a 1

Comment: @zeca_abc The attached link indicates how to build the MRE, it would also be good if you review [ask] and pass the [tour] so that you know the dynamics of SO.

Comment: @zeca_abc as said, we need a MRE in order to really help you. Please consider that creating a *valid* MRE could take some time (even hours), but that's worth it. Right now we cannot really help you: the code you gave us is insufficient to properly understand what you're doing and what you want to achieve (even if you tried to explain it). Take your time, ensure that *anybody* could understand what it does, and could help you just by copying, pasting and running your example. Hint: if you copy the code of your edit preview, paste it in a new file and you cannot run it, it means it's not a MRE.

Comment: @zeca_abc Use a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html): `self.btngroup = QButtonGroup(); for btn in (a, b, c, d, e): self.btngroup.addButton(btn)`. Then you can get the checked button with `self.btngroup.checkedButton()` or connect a slot to [one of the signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#signals).

Comment: @ekhumoro after some hours of work I figured out one solution, the real problem was in the return statement I was using, your suggestion for the Qbuttongroup helped me a lot in discovering it, so thank you very much!!

Comment: @musicamante thank you for the way you've delivered these useful tips too!!